# Error 1004 on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have five worksheet in all that are using the below code which is stored in a workbook. The first worksheet works perfectly well with the code. The second spreadsheet can check for the first item before returning the error. The subsequent third and fourth worksheet return the error immediately. The fifth worksheet on the other hand return error 400. May I know is my code the source of the problem or it's the checkbox because I copied and paste from the first worksheet.

```
Sub test5()
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    d = 2
    i = 0
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    For Row = 3 To FinalRow
         If Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, "S")) Then
                i = i + 1
                d = d + 1
                MyFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, "S").Value
                If Dir(MyFile) <> "" Then
                    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i). _
                        Object.Value = True ' <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Error occurs here
                    With ActiveSheet.Cells(d, "F")
                        .Value = Now
                        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
                        'If (ActiveSheet.Cells(d, "F") - ActiveSheet.Cells(d, "G") >= 0) Then
                        '    ActiveSheet.Cells(d, "F").Font.Color = vbRed
                        'End If
                        If (.Value - .Offset(0, 1).Value) >= 0 Then
                            .Font.Color = vbRed
                        Else
                            .Font.Color = vbBlack
                        End If
                    End With
                   ' i = i + 1
                    'd = d + 1
                End If
         End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The program terminates after stepping into this line of code:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i). _ Object.Value = True
```

Comment: On what line do you get these errors? Try stepping through your code in debug mode and watching how your variables evolve ([instructions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)). If that doesn't help, then I suggest you see this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i). _
                    Object.Value = True

Comment: Please put question clarifications in the question itself, not in comments. Your question can be edited by clicking the "edit" link.

Answer (score 0):

OLEObject does **not** have a member called **value**. If you are trying to display the OLEObject, use **visible** instead

`ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Visible = True`

See all OLEObject members here :

[OLEObject Object Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb242385%28v=office.12%29.aspx)